# OData Adding related entities to two tables at once

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, odata

I am consuming a Odata service in C#. I have two poco's Contact and Address. Address is a nullable FK of ContactID. I need to get Odata to add both Contact and Address. I have tried AddLink and SetLink but get an `Navigation Routing error`. Here are poco's classes:

```
Contact
[key]
public Guid ContactID {get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}
public ICollection<Address> ContactAddresses{get;set;}

Address
[key]
public Guid AddressID{get;set;}
public string Address {get;set;}
[ForeignKey["Contact"]
public Guid? ContactID
[ForeignKey["Tenant"]{get;set;}
public Guid? TenantID {get;set;}
public Contact Contact{get;set;}
public Tenant Tenant{get;set;}
```

I am consuming OData Service in C#. The OData Models are Addresses and Contacts.

Comment: You are using OData v3, right? Which server framework are you using? WCF Data Service or Web API? Consider to show us an example HTTP-Request and the result. You can use Fiddler for it.

Comment: I'm using odata 4 and webapi 2

Comment: You need a `CreateRef` function in your controller to use odata v4 $ref. [Here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4) is an detailed example.

Comment: I have already done that but how do I get this by consuming the service in c# addlink set link or add related object

Comment: AddRelatedObject would fire a request to 'POST Contact(x)/ContactAddresses', have you checked whether your service support such route.

Comment: Got add and set link to do that I have one more problem. The code on the asp.net odata section for relationships do not work for me in version 4 in getting the key from the key segments the odata properties .model is aways null and when I try the depreciated get odata path it finds no segments.

Comment: here is a link to the web page [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4). GetKeyFromUri<TKey>.